# Implement Batch Process Using Producer Consumer

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

Batch

1. read text from file or SQL
2. parse the text into words
3. load the words into SQL

Today
.NET 4.0
Step 1 is very fast. 
Steps 2 and 3 are about the same length (avg 0.1 second) for the same size file.
On step 3 insert using BackGroundWorker and wait for last to complete.
Everything else is on the main thread.

On a big load will do this several million times.

Need step 3 to be serial and in the same order as 1.
This is to keep the SQL table PK index from fracturing.
Tried step 3 in parallel and fracturing the index killed it.
This data is fed sorted by the PK.
Other indexes are dropped at the start of the load then rebuilt at the end of the load.

Where this process is not effective is when the size of text changes.
And the size of the text from file to file does change drastically.
What I would like is to queue 1 and 2 so 3 is kept as busy as possible.

Need step 3 to dequeue the files in order they were enqueued in 1 (even if it waits).

Need a maximum queue size for memory management (like 4-10).

Would like to have step 2 parallel with up to 4 concurrent.

Moving to .NET 4.5.

**Asking for general guidance on how to implement this?**

I am learning that this is a producer consumer pattern.
If this is not a producer consumer pattern please let me know so I can change the title.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `files.AsParallel().AsOrdered()`?

Comment: @DaxFohl Step 1. is already very fast.  And the text can be from SQL or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think TPL Dataflow would be a good way to do this:

For step 2, you would use a `TransformBlock` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 4 and `BoundedCapacity` also set to 4, so that its queues are empty when working. It will produce the items in the same order as they came in, you don't have to do anything special for that. For step 3, use an `ActionBlock`, with `BoundedCapacity` set to your limit. Then link the two together and start sending items to the `TransformBlock`, ideally using something like `await stepTwoBlock.SendAsync(…)`, to asynchronously wait if the queue is full.

In code, it would look something like:

```
async Task ProcessData()
{
    var stepTwoBlock = new TransformBlock<OriginalText, ParsedText>(
        text => Parse(text),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
            BoundedCapacity = 4
        });
    var stepThreeBlock = new ActionBlock<ParsedText>(
        text => LoadIntoDatabase(text),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 10 });
    stepTwoBlock.LinkTo(
        stepThreeBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    // this is step one:
    foreach (var id in IdsToProcess)
    {
        OriginalText text = ReadText(id);
        await stepTwoBlock.SendAsync(text);
    }

    stepTwoBlock.Complete();
    await stepThreeBlock.Completion;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is going to take me a while to test.  The stepTwoBlock takes in 4 at a time and then when all four are complete it will grab the next 4?  So it will take as long as the longest of the 4?  If that keeps em in order then it is worth it.

Comment: It doesn't work exactly like that. If the first item (with the lowest id) from those currently in step 2 finishes first, then a new one will start processing right away (assuming there is free space in the step 3 block). But what you describe could happen if you're unlucky, because the block will always keep at most 4 items, even if it can't do anything with some of them for now. If this turns out to be a problem, you might try to increase the capacity of the step 2 block (and possibly decrease the capacity of the step 3 block, the keep the memory usage the same).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but can't give you check until I test and this something I want to learn so it is going to take me bit.